# Checking if a prime ideal is principal for a particular cubic field

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

Consider the totally real cubic field $K = \mathbb{Q} (\alpha) = \mathbb{Q} [x]/(f)$ defined by $f = x^{3} - x^{2} - 9 x + 10$ (see https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.3.1957.1). The ring of integers in this particular case is $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z} [\alpha] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$.

Now $\mathfrak{p} = (2,\alpha)$ is a prime ideal of norm $2$, and it is not principal, as one can check with computer calculations. (In fact it is a generator of the class group, which is $C_2$.) I was wondering if there's an easy way to see that.

- There are algorithms (based on LLL reduction) that verify if any given ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$ is principal, but I expect some better explanation that may be checked with less computations.
- In fact, computer calculations confirm that there are no elements of norm $2$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and this would be enough to conclude that $\mathfrak{p}$ is not principal. Curiously, it seems like the equation $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}} (a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2) = 2$, while not having solutions $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, seems to have solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ for all small $p^k$. I checked this experimentally, but the cubic form in question may in fact violate the local-global principle, so there may be no easy way to show that there are no integer solutions.

Is there a good way to see that $\mathfrak{p}$ is not a principal ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of computing the class group, you should have shown that $(\alpha-2) = \mathfrak p^2$. Therefore *if* $\mathfrak p = (\beta)$ for some $\beta \in \mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\alpha]$, we'd have $(\alpha-2) = (\beta)^2 = (\beta^2)$, so $\beta^2 = (\alpha - 2)\varepsilon$ for some unit $\varepsilon \in \mathcal O_K^\times$.  We want to show $(\alpha-2)\varepsilon$ is not a square in $\mathcal O_K$ for all $\varepsilon \in \mathcal O_K^\times$. How can we do that?

You might think "Oh no, I have to compute the unit group, which has rank 2. How do you compute a rank 2 unit group by hand?"  We don't need the full unit group. What we need is to understand the unit group *modulo squares* because squared units can be absorbed into the hypothetical $\beta^2$.

The unit theorem tells us that $\mathcal O_K^\times = \pm u^\mathbf Z \times v^\mathbf Z$ for some independent units $u$ and $v$, which would mean $\mathcal O_K^\times/(\mathcal O_K^\times)^2 = \langle -1, \overline{u}, \overline{v}\rangle \cong (\mathbf Z/(2))^3$.  A computer algebra package says fundamental units for $K$ are $u := \alpha-1$ and $v := \alpha-3$.  It is easy to check $u$ and $v$ have norm $1$, so they are both units. It now suffices to show *not* that these are fundamental units (that is far more work than we need!), but that they together with $-1$ generate the units modulo squares. Since the structure of the unit group modulo squares is (as a multiplicative group with $\mathbf Z/(2)$ acting as exponents) $3$-dimensional, it suffices to show $-1$, $u$, and $v$ are independent modulo squares: none of the $7$ products (corresponding in linear algebra language to nontrivial "$\mathbf F_2$-linear combinations")
$$
-1, u, v, -u, -v, uv, -uv
$$
is a square. Obviously $-1$ is not a square in the number field, since cubic fields have a real embedding. To show the remaining six units are not squares, here are two approaches. The second is more robust (viable for testing a number is not a higher power rather than just not a square).

Method 1: If something is a square, then under every real embedding it has to be mapped to a positive number.  The polynomial $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 - 9x + 10$ has three real roots, so you have three real embeddings to use. The real roots of $f(x)$ are $\alpha_1 \approx -3.0409$, $\alpha_2 \approx 1.1294$, and $\alpha_3 \approx 2.9115$.  I will write $u_j$ and $v_j$ for the images of $u = \alpha-1$ and $v = \alpha -3$ under the real embedding that sends $\alpha$ to $\alpha_j$.

Since $\alpha_1 < 0$ we have $u_1 < 0$, $v_1 < 0$, and $-u_1v_1 < 0$, so $u$ and $v$ and $-uv$ are not squares. Since $\alpha_2$ is between $1$ and $2$, we have $-u_2 < 0$ and $u_2v_2 < 0$, so $-u$ and $uv$ are not squares. That leaves just $-v = 3 - \alpha$, whose image under all real embeddings is positive, so we did not succeed in showing $-v$ is not a square in $\mathcal O_K$ by finding a negative image under some real embedding.  It's time to move on to Method 2.

Method 2: To show a number $\gamma$ in $\mathcal O_K$ is not a square, find a prime ideal $\mathfrak q$ such that $\gamma \bmod \mathfrak q$ is not a square in $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak q$. (This is a fancy version of the fact that 10007 is not a square in $\mathbf Z$ since it's not a square mod $10$, or not a square mod $5$.)  I was able to apply this idea to show $u, v, -u, -v, uv, -uv$ are not squares by using the unique prime ideals of norm $5$, $11$, and $13$, and a prime ideal of norm $17$ (there are three of those).

For example, the prime $\mathfrak q$ of norm $5$ is $(5,\alpha)$, so $\alpha \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak q$ and thus in the residue field $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak q \cong \mathbf Z/(5)$ we have $v = \alpha-3 \equiv -3 \equiv 2$ and $2 \not= \Box$ in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$.  So $v$ is not a square in $\mathcal O_K$.  Also $-v \equiv 3 \mathfrak q$ and $3 \not= \Box$ in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, so $-v$ is not a square in $\mathcal O_K$ either. We  handled all the other units by Method 1, so I'll stop here with Method 2, but you should check that Method 2 handles everything by reducing each of the 6 units modulo some prime ideal of norm $5$, $11$, $13$, and $17$ to verify that it is not a square modulo a prime ideal and thus is not a square in $\mathcal O_K$.

Our goal is to show $(\alpha-2)\varepsilon$ is not a square for every unit $\varepsilon$. For this task, $\varepsilon$ only matters modulo unit squares.
We know $\mathcal O_K^\times/(\mathcal O_K^\times)^2$ is represented by $\{1,-1,u,v,-u,-v,uv,-uv\}$, so it remains to show the eight products
$$
\alpha-2, -(\alpha-2), u(\alpha-2), v(\alpha-2), -u(\alpha-2), -v(\alpha-2), uv(\alpha-2), -uv(\alpha-2)
$$
are all not squares in $\mathcal O_K$.  You can try this using Method 1 (real embeddings) or Method 2 (reduction modulo well-chosen prime ideals). For example, under the real embedding sending $\alpha$ to $\alpha_1 \approx -3.0409$, we have $\alpha_1 - 2 \approx -5.0409$, $u_1 = \alpha_1 - 1 \approx -4.0409$ and $v_1 = \alpha_1 - 3 \approx -6.0409$, so (i) $\alpha_1-2 < 0$, (ii) $-u_1(\alpha_1-2) < 0$, $-v_1(\alpha_1-2) < 0$, and (iii) $u_1v_1(\alpha_1-2) < 0$. Therefore $\alpha-2$, $-u(\alpha-2)$, $-v(\alpha-2)$, and $uv(\alpha-2)$ are all not squares.  It remains for you to check that $-(\alpha-2)$, $u(\alpha-2)$, $v(\alpha-2)$, and $-uv(\alpha-2)$ are all not squares. Have fun!

Comment: Looking at $\mathcal{O}_K^\times/(\mathcal{O}_K^\times)^2$ a very nice idea, thank you very much!